# Adjectives to distinguish males' & females' clothes and accessories

Tags: word-usage, word-request

What adjective I can use to refer to specific sort of clothes or anything that has been designed to be used by women or men to imply that they are dedicated to "men" and in contrary specific for "women" use?

I've always said that these are "**ladies'**" and "**for men"[which is not an adjective]**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words that are used usually for this purpose in the industry are:

- for her/him
- for ladies/women/men
- women/ladies/men (e.g ladies' pants, men's shirt)

Answer (score 0):

One word sometimes used in British English is "gents'" - for example, "The building has two toilets, a ladies' and a gents'." "A new gents' hairdresser has opened on the High Street."